# why eclipse is not able to import package for hbase?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hbase, bigdata, cloudera

I am using Cloudera Hadoop VMWare 4.7.0.
While writting hbase code in eclipse i was getting error at import line.
So, please tell me do i need to use any jar or any plugin to resolve this issue?
How to import packages for hbase program?
I tried to find out the solution on internet but could not get any thing.
Please help me friends.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is there a message?

Comment: i am getting error message like "the import org.apache can not be resolved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer of above problem.
I just added the jar for hbase into classpath and issue was resolved.
I got that jar file form following link:-
[Link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.90.2/hbase-0.90.2.jar)